# How to have methods of an jQuery array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm searching for a way to access methods of an jQuery array item.
My code is :

```
$('.cell-news').each( function()
{
    if ( $('.cell-news')[i].style.display === 'block' )
    {
        $('.cell-news')[i].style.display = 'none';
        if ( i === $('.cell-news').length - 1 )
            $('.cell-news')[0].style.display = 'block';
        else
            $('.cell-news')[i + 1].style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    }
    i++;
} );
```

I want to replace my `style.display` by an `.animate()` or `.slideUp/Down()` but my item value is a dom element, when i print `$('.cell-news')[i]` on my `console.log` i get this :

```
<div class="cell-news" style="display: none;"></div>
```

If i don't use `$(this)` it's because i can't get my first array item and the i + 1 item.

How can i resolve this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: `$('.cell-news:eq(' + i + ')');`?

Comment: you don't need to define or increment `i`. you don't need to re-select ".cell-news".

Comment: Why do you use Jquery and then you go back to standard DOM elements, keep using jquery objects your code will be clearer. For exemple don't write `$('.cell-news')[i].style.display = 'none'` but `$('.cell-news').eq(i).css("display","none");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`:eq(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the correct element:

```
$('.cell-news:eq(' + i + ')').animate({
    ...
});
```